# Apache tomcat server error

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

today my avast updated the my java and now i cant do anything with my web service. 
the localhost:9999 is showing the pic but if i click on the services i got this error:

type Exception report

```
>     message Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
>     
>     description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>     
>     exception
>     
>     javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>     root cause
>     
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils
>       org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.setDeploymentFeatures(DeploymentEngine.java:1061)
>       org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:154)
>       org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:228)
>       org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>       org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
>       org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please help me because i'm stucked here!

Thank you!

Comment: don't vote down give me an answer pls!

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution.

```
Reinstall the Java
```